# imagePullSecrets on default service account don't seem to work

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, azure-aks

I am basically trying to pull GCR images from Azure kubernetes cluster.
I have the folowing for my default service account:

```
kubectl get serviceaccounts default -o yaml                            
apiVersion: v1
imagePullSecrets:
- name: gcr-json-key-stg
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2019-12-24T03:42:15Z"
  name: default
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "151571"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/serviceaccounts/default
  uid: 7f88785d-05de-4568-b050-f3a5dddd8ad1
secrets:
- name: default-token-gn9vb
```

If I add the same `imagePullSecret` to individual deployments, it works. So, the secret is correct. However, when I use it for a default service account, I get a `ImagePullBackOff` error which on describing confirms that it's a permission issue.

Am I missing something?
I have made sure that my deployment is not configured with any other specific serviceaccount and should be using the default serviceaccount.

Comment: why do you think this should work? how it should work?

Comment: I thought the default serviceaccount is the associated to all the resources not having any serviceaccount associated to it explicitly. If not, how should it work? @4c74356b41

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, the problem was that the `default` service account that I added the `imagePullSecret` wasn't in the same namespace.
Once, I patched the default service account in that namespace, it works perfectly well.

Comment: No entire info in the question and then it caused the error. So no one can solve your question except you. Well Down!

Answer (score 0):

After you add the secret for pulling the image to the service account, then you need to add the service account into your pod or deployment. For example:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: helloworld-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: helloworld
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: helloworld
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: helloworld
        image: yourPrivateRegistry/image:tag
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      serviceAccountName: pull-image     # your service account
```

And the service account `pull-image` looks like this:

[image]

Comment: If you don't specify `serviceaccount` name, by default it uses the `default` serviceaccount.

Comment: @kosta Yes, but what different? You did not give all the YAML files, so how can people figure out the error for you?! What I can tell is that the service account can work well.